# whether the set is dense?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

$X=C[0,1]$ with sup norm,

$S =\lbrace f\in X: \int _0^1f(t)dt \neq 0  \rbrace $ then how to decide whether S dense, nowhere dense ?

The function which are outside S have integral $0$ so they are zero almost everywhere on $[0,1]$. Again all the positive$(f(x)>0$ $\forall x) $ and negative functions will be there in S. intuitively it is clear to me that this set is dense.

I have tried considering a function $f\to \int _0^1f$ so under this map $S$ is inverse image of $(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$. somehow i am not able to connect all this.. can anyone give some hint?

thank you.

Comment: A hint? Maybe show that every function $f$ that has $\int _0 ^1 f = 0$ can be approximated by other functions with integral not vanishing.
(The sequence of functions you construct must, obviously, depened on f).

Comment: I m not able to do so yet..

Comment: Try to find a sequence of functions $f_n\in S$ such that $\|f_n\|_{\infty}\to 0$. That would serve as both intuition and a building-block for your proof.

Comment: No, functions with 0 integral are *not* a.e. 0. A sine function on a suitable domain has integral 0, as the positive part and negative part cancel out. The codomain is all of the reals, not just positive reals. If that were the case, the only continuous function with 0 integral would be the 0-function...

Comment: The mapping remark (inverse image of open set) does show that $S$ is not nowhere dense, being open in $X$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Can you elaborate on this? Or review my answer? It seems that S is indeed dense...

Comment: Don't you see that the integral of a function is a continuous mapping from functions to numbers? That is, if you have a function and you make a "small" change to the function (pushing its graph up or down in once place  by a tiny amount), it's integral shouldn't change too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of:$\int_0 ^1 f = 0 $ does not implify $f \overset{\text{a.e.}}{=} 0$.

My attempt: Let $f\in C_\infty [0,1]$ if $\int_0 ^1 f \ne 0 $ then take the sequence $S \ni f_n = f$ obviously $f_n \rightarrow f$.
**Otherwise**, consider the sequence $f_n = f+ \frac{1}{n} $

Indeed $f\in C_\infty$ (as sum of such) and since $f \notin S$ we have: 
$$\int _0 ^1 f_n = \int _0 ^{1} f +\int _0 ^1 \frac{1}{n}=0+1/n \ne 0$$

That implies $f_n \in f$. We also have $\|f_n - f\|_\infty =\|\frac{1}{n}\|_\infty \rightarrow 0$.

*Followup question*: I'm interested to see if someone can approach this via functional analysis. considering the functional $T \in C^\text{#}_\infty$:

$Tf = \int_0^1 f$. We can see $T$ is bounded since $|Tf| \leq |\int_0^1 f | \leq \|f\|_\infty$ which implies the kernel is closed. We also know that $\mathrm{Codim} \ker T =1$, but i can't get further with this.

Comment: Sure, every point in $X$ is a sequential limit of points from $S$, so indeed $S$ is dense. This makes it automatically nowhere dense (as $\operatorname{int}(\overline{S}) = X \neq \emptyset$...). Using $T$ we see that $S = T^{-1}[\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}]$ so $S$ is also open (another reason to not be nowhere dense). So $S$ is open and dense.

Comment: Also note that the kernel of $T$ is then closed and nowhere dense, of course.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you for that interesting remark. I was not familiar with "nowhere dense" (until now). But, if i may ask another question; how did the fact that $S$ is open contributed to our understanding that $S$ is dense? (I see that it did, however, help us understand it is nowehere dense).

Comment: You asked about $S$ being nowhere dense in the question (!). No, $S$ being open has nothing to do with being dense. It just shows that $X \setminus S = \ker T$ (not $S$) is nowhere dense though. Nowhere dense is relevant in Baire's theorem, so you'll need to know it in maths.

Comment: thanks everyone. @HennoBrandsma in this case i knew that the set is not nowhere dense but is there any general method to check whether the set is nowhere dense or not?

Comment: @Prajakta a set is nowhere dense iff its complement contains an open dense set.

Answer (score 3):

A functional analysis aproach:

Lema: If $V$ is a vector subspace of a normed space $X$, then $V^\circ=\emptyset$ or $V=X$ (here, $V^\circ$ is interior of $V$).

Proof: Suppose $V\neq X$ and $V^\circ\neq\emptyset$. Set $x_0\in V^\circ$. How $T:X\to X$ given by $Tx=x-x_0$ is continuos, we can suppose $x_0=0$. Now, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(0,\epsilon)\subseteq V$. Take $v\in X\backslash V$. Then, $v\neq 0$ and there is a non zero multiple of $v$ that is in $B(0,\epsilon)$, say $tv$. Then, $tv\in V$. Thus, every multiple of $tv$ belongs to $V$. In particular $v$. This contradiction shows that $V=X$ or $V^\circ=\emptyset$.

Now, let $T:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ given by $Tf=\int_0^1f(x)dx$. Note that $S=X\backslash\mathrm{Ker}(T)$. Then $\overline{S}=X\backslash\mathrm{Ker}(T)^\circ=X$ cause $\mathrm{Ker}(T)$ is a subspace of $X$ and it isn't $X$.

From that, $S$ is dense in $X$. Also, $S$ is an open set. Furthermore, note that we don't use that $T$ is continous. Then, if $T\neq 0$ is any linear operator, $\overline{X\backslash \mathrm{Ker}(T)}=X\backslash \mathrm{Ker}(T)^\circ=X$. Thus, $X\backslash\mathrm{Ker}(T)$ always is dense if $T$ isn't the null operator.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

$\displaystyle S=\left\{f\in X:\int_0^1f(t)\,dt \not=0\right\}=\left\{f\in X:\int_0^1f(t)\,dt<0\right\}\cup \left\{f\in X:\int_0^1f(t)\,dt>0\right\}$.

What is $\bar{S}$ ?

> $\bar{S}=C[0,1]=X.$ and so ........